# Apply a function for each pair of columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
Day  A1 A2 B1 B2 C1 C2
Mon   1  0  0  1  0  1
Tue   1  0  1  0  0  1
Wed   0  1  1  0  1  0
Thu   0  1  0  1  1  0

df <- data.frame(A1=c(1,1,0,0),A2=c(0,0,1,1),B1=c(0,1,1,0),B2=c(1,0,0,1),C1=c(0,0,1,1),C2=c(1,1,0,0), row.names=c('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu'))
```

I want to get as an output the days that have have X1=1 and X2=0, classified by letter. For example, for letter A, Mon and Tue match the criteria A1=1 and A2=0.

Such that the output is:

A list:

```
$A
Mon
Tue

$B
Tue
Wed

$C
Wed
Thu
```

Or a dataframe:

```
Lett Day
A    Mon
A    Tue
B    Tue
B    Wed
C    Wed
C    Thu
```

I tried to to the following:

For A:

```
 A <- df$A1 == 1 & df$A2 == 0
```

I would get a logical vector like:

```
T
T
F
F
```

Then match them with the days of the initial db:

```
A <- cbind(db[1], A)
```

And filter the "TRUE" values to get the output

```
A
Mon 
Tue
```

I could do this for every letter but the script would be too long and the problem is that I could have any number of letters (A, B.. Z)

Comment: Can you make it clear what are X1 and X2?

Comment: @Metrics Pretty sure `X` is meant to be wildcard `*` for each letter: A,B,C...

Comment: Exactly, X = {A, B, .. Z)

Answer (score 2):

This is one way using `split.default`:

```
grped.cols <- split.default(df, substr(names(df), 1, 1))
cond <- function(x) row.names(df)[x[1] & ! x[2]]
lapply(grped.cols, cond)
# $A
# [1] "Mon" "Tue"
# 
# $B
# [1] "Tue" "Wed"
# 
# $C
# [1] "Wed" "Thu"
```