# apply t.test on every consecutive pair of columns of a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have a time series data frame in the table below. I would like to do a paired-test in R between the 00:00 column and the 00:15 column. Then between the 00:15 and the next one, and so on.

My data looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64qPv.png).

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/64qPv.png

Comment: checked this one? http://stackoverflow.com/q/19915580/3871924 or that one http://stackoverflow.com/q/5233308/3871924

Comment: @agenis, I dont think that will work for me. I have just put an example but I actually have thousands of columns. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: That sounds like a bad plan.

Comment: I want to know whether I should or should not group my columns. That's why I need the paired analysis. Why do you think that's a bad plan? Do you have another one that satisfies this purpose? @Roland

Comment: Please consult a statistician.

Comment: It probably is. I am just really new to R. Thank you @agenis. I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a for loop:

```
res=NULL
for(i in 2:ncol(df)){
res<-c(res, t.test(df[, i-1], df[, i], paired=T)$p.value)
}
print(res)
#### [1] 0.87346300 0.29767460 0.07232177
```

Or with the `apply` family of functions:

```
sapply(2:ncol(df), function(x) t.test(df[, x-1], df[, x], paired=T)$p.value)
#### [1] 0.87346300 0.29767460 0.07232177
```

I see a third solution using `rowr::rollApply`, it applies a function to a rolling window, here by 2 (to the transposed of your data)

```
library(rowr)
rollApply(t(df), function(x) t.test(x[1, ], x[2, ], paired=T)$p.value, minimum=2, window=2)
#### [1] 0.87346300 0.29767460 0.07232177
```

I recommend to adjust the confidence level to take into account the multiplicity of comparisons (something like `alpha/(ncol(df)-1)`)

your data:

```
set.seed(1)
df=as.matrix(data.frame(rnorm(4),rnorm(4), rnorm(4), rnorm(4)))
```